# sticky navbar not hiding scrollable element

Tags: javascript, html, css

As you can see in the demo below, the content with red background color is not being hided by the sticky navbar.

My questions are:

- What should I do to correct this? i.e. the content would not show at the navbar's place.
- How can I scroll the whole main div in x-direction though I already set `overflow-x: auto`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        .main {
            height: 100px;
            max-width: 100px;
            overflow-x: auto;
        }
        .nav {
            position: sticky;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
        }
        .rows {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            overflow-y: auto;
            background: #da1039;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="nav">navnavnavnavnavnavnavnavnavn</div>
        <div class="rows">
            <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
            <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
            <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
            <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
            <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
            <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
            <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
            <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
            <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
            <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
            <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

giv `.nav` some `background-color`:

```
.nav { 
                position: sticky; 
                display: inline-block;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                background-color: white;
            }
```

and make the following changes to `.row`

```
.rows {
            display:inline-block;
            background: #da1039;
        }
```

Final code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
        .main {
            height: 100px;
            max-width: 100px;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }
        .nav { position: sticky; 
            display: inline-block;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            background-color: white;
        }
        .rows {
            display:inline-block;
            background: #da1039;
        }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="main">
        <div class="nav">navnavnavnavnavnavnavnavnavn</div>
        <div class="rows">
            <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
            <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
            <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
            <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
            <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
            <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
            <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
            <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
            <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
            <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
            <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: scrolling main div? like the ```.row``` div?

Comment: Yes, scroll the nav and rows simultaneously in x direction

Comment: You removed the sticky nav, that's not acceptable.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain this? why does making them inline can achieve this?

Comment: sorry if this sounds rude but docs are readily available and you should consider reading them.

Comment: Which doc should I check, the CSS thing is much more like an experience-oriented tech compared to other languages. Would you mind give me a hint about where should I look for or search for it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add background color to `.nav` class:

```
.nav {
    background-color: white
}
```

Then content should be hidden behind the sticky nav.

Answer (score 0):

You can change position of the `.nav` to fixed

```
.nav {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `overflow-y` property to `rows` class, so it will be scrollable only through this element not whole `main` div

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Title</title>
    <style>
      .main {
        height: 100px;
        max-width: 100px;
        padding-top: 7px;
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
      }
      .nav {
        position: sticky;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        max-width: 100px;
      }
      .rows {
        max-width: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
        overflow-y: auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        background: #da1039;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="nav">loremipsumdolorsitamet</div>
      <div class="rows">
        <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
        <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
        <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
        <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
        <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
        <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
        <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
        <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
        <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
        <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
        <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I actually want to scroll the main div，but currently only rows div is scrollable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving the navbar a background color, for example, white or black. But if you will give black then make sure you change the nav content color to white.

```
.nav {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <style>
    .main {
      height: 150px;
      max-width: 150px;
      overflow-x: auto;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      overflow-y: auto;
      background: #da1039;
    }
    
    .nav {
      position: sticky;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: #FFFFFF;
      z-index: 999;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>


  <div class="main">
    <div class="nav">Haha i don't move(sticky nav)</div>
    <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
    <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
    <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
    <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
    <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
    <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
    <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
    <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
    <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
    <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
    <div>asdddssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssdddddddd</div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

### References

```
>My CSS instincts
>
>Stackoverflow
```